# PHP magic constants - automatically passed to function?

Tags: php, magic-constants

I wrote a simple access control system which reads an array of access strings, and return true or false depending on the result.

I would call it as follows (for example in a method `list_user_data` of class `User`): `

```
if (current_user_can(__CLASS__, __METHOD__)) { 
    ... 
}
```

and inside there, it checks if the current user has permission to access method `list_user_data` in class `User`.

It works, but I find it annoying that I always have to specify `__CLASS__` and `__METHOD__` in the call. Is there a way to get those values **from within** the `current_user_can` function for the **calling** function so that I can simply call `current_user_can()` without having to pass the magic constants?

My code works as is, but I am thinking it could be improved.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Worth looking into [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) perhaps.

Comment: Ah, that works, thank you. Please post as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) should return the calling function in the 2nd entry (index 1), for example:

```
<?php

function current_user_can()
{
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(false, 2);
    // ToDo: Check if $backtrace[1] (and especially the class-key of that) actually exist...
    //       It should always (although the class key might not if this function isn't called from within a class), since this function is being called
    //       but it's still a good habbit to check array keys before accessing the array
    $callerClass = $backtrace[1]["class"];
    $callerMethod = $backtrace[1]["function"];

    // ToDo: implementation of check, in this example $callerClass would be "User" and $callerMethod would be "list_user_data"

    return true;
}

class User {
    public function list_user_data() {
        if (current_user_can())
        {

        }
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->list_user_data();
```